# Error durante la implementacion de cocoon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tengo un modelo `Describete` que esta asociado a un usuario. En la misma vista de describete debería haber un botón de 'agregar mas', pero este no aparece. Teniendo el siguiente error:

> undefined local variable or method `form'

este si lo cambio  a f me dirá que lo cambie a form.

siguiendo la documentación he hecho los siguientes pasos.

para `_describetes_fields.html`:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :perfil %>
    <%= f.text_area :perfil %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <p>¿En que te capacitaste?</p>
    <%= f.text_field :carrera %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <p>Ins.text_field :centro %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <p>Año de tu capacitacion</p>
    <%= f.text_field :year %>
  </div>

  <%= link_to_remove_association 'delete', f %>
```

para `_form.html` (de describete view):

```
<%= form_with(model: describete, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if describete.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(describete.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this describete from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% describete.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <p>Perfil profesional</p>
    <%= form.text_area :perfil %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <p>¿En que te capacitaste?</p>
    <%= form.text_field :carrera %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <p>Institucion o centro de capacitacion</p>
    <%= form.text_field :centro %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <p>Año de tu capacitacion</p>
    <%= form.text_field :year %>
  </div>

  <h3>Mas</h3>
  <%= form.fields_for :describetes do |describete| %>
   <%= render 'describetes_fields', :form => describete %>
  <% end %>

  <div>
    <%= link_to_add_association 'Add more', form, :describetes, :partial => 'describetes/describetes_fields' %>
  </div>


  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

y mi modelo `describete.rb`:

```
class Describete < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user

    has_many :describetes
    belongs_to :describete

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :describetes, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

end
```

Comment: Agrega más código de tu archivo `_form.html`. Sospecho que el error está en cómo tienes definido el campo de formulario en el bloque de `semantic_form_for`

Comment: hola amigo @AlterLagos

Answer (score 1):

El mensaje de error es confuso, sin embargo puedo ver el problema en tu código justo en esta línea:

```
<%= render 'describetes_fields', :form => describete %>
```

Estás utilizando `form` cuando deberías utilizar `f`, ya que el *partial* utiliza `f` (este es el comportamiento por defecto de *Cocoon*`):

```
<%= render 'describetes_fields', :f => describete %>
```